# How Can I disable user account of admin group on a remote machine with the help of VBS

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I need do something like this code

```
strUser = "myUser"
strComputer = "myremoteComuter"
strPassword = "myPassword_"

Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "/" & strUser & ",user",strUser,strPassword)


If Err.Number = 0 Then
objUser.AccountDisabled = true
objUser.SetInfo
End If
```

But there is not such methods `GetObject` that takes 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a snip of code:

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1
Set objUser = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://MyDomain/UserNameToEnable,user",AdminUserName,AdminUserPassword, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
objUser.AccountDisabled = true
objUser.SetInfo
```